# How to parse field name and context with json_value in SQL server 2019

Tags: sql-server

Description of problem
In a SQL table with column name Tags it is populated with the following content:

```
[{"Tags":"\"Cost Center\": \"009649\",\"Security Level\": \"High\",\"Status\": \"Active\",\"Title\" : \"DRAIM\""}]
```

Based on the following statement I get the following value

```
  DECLARE @json_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
  {"Tags":{"Cost Center": "009649","Security Level": "High", "Status": "Active","Title": "DRAIM"}}';

   SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.Tags')
  -- FROM OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.Tags')
  [{"Tags":"\"Cost Center\": \"009649\",\"Security Level\": \"High\",\"Status\": \"Active\",\"Title\" : \"DRAIM\""}]
```

Output:

[image]

Wat I would like to achieve.
From this json string I just want to extract the Cost center information to a column.

I try to achieve the CostCenter information in a new column with the following statements.

```
SELECT
       [ID]
       ,[Tags]
       , JSON_VALUE('{' + Tags + '}', '$.\"Cost Center\') AS CostCenter
      -- , JSON_VALUE('{' + Tags + '}', '$.\"Cost Center\"') AS CostCenter
FROM [dbo].[table_details]
```

I see the following error message.
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '' is found at position 2.

I've already tried several options to solve this error, but I can't figure it out.
Does anyone have any advice on which json value can be used to show the associated value in a Costcenter column.

Thanks for contributing ideas.

Comment: Please add what is the expected output

Comment: Are you sure, that `[{"Tags":"\"Cost Center\": \"009649\",\"Security Level\": \"High\",\"Status\": \"Active\",\"Title\" : \"DRAIM\""}]` is the actual JSON content?

Comment: Basically the content in the column Tags looks like this
 "Cost Center": "009649","Security Level": "High","Status": "Active","Title": "DRAIM"

When run statement SELECT TOP 1
tags
FROM [dbo].[emc0001_raw_export]
FOR JSON Auto

I see the following result
[{"tags":"\"Cost Center\": \"009649\",\"Security Level\": \"High\",\"Status\": \"Active\",\"Title\": \"DRAIM\""}]

which is exactly as described

Answer (score 0):

Since your tags values aren't json, you need to remake it a bit:

```sql
DECLARE @json_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
  {"Tags":"\"Cost Center\": \"009649\",\"Security Level\": \"High\",\"Status\": \"Active\",\"Title\" : \"DRAIM\""}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE('{' + JSON_VALUE(@json_string, '$.Tags') + '}', '$."Cost Center"')
```

Basicly, you extract the Tags string first, then convert it to json by appending {} around it, and finally, you get the value by using JSON_VALUE

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This solution solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use the `PIVOT` function to transform rows to columns:

This will return all the data from your json.

```
DECLARE @json_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
  {"Tags":{"Cost Center": "009649","Security Level": "High", "Status": "Active","Title": "DRAIM"}}';

WITH cte as (
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.Tags')
)
select [Cost Center], [Security Level], Status, Title
from cte
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for [key] in ([Cost Center], [Security Level], Status, Title)
) piv;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This is a workable solution!